# How can I get an array value from my dictionary?

Tags: c#

In my code, I created a dictionary where the value is an array on integers. What I need to do is take one of those values within the array and set that as a value somewhere else. How would I do that? For reference, the dictionary looks like this:

```
public IDictionary<string, int[]> Statistics { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, int[]>()
{
    { "STR", new int[] { 0, 0, 0 } }, 
    { "DEX", new int[] { 0, 0, 0 } },
    { "CON", new int[] { 0, 0, 0 } }, 
    { "INT", new int[] { 0, 0, 0 } },
    { "WIS", new int[] { 0, 0, 0 } }, 
    { "CHA", new int[] { 0, 0, 0 } } 
};
```

So, I want to take the second integer in the array of whichever key I need, and then assign that value somewhere else.

Comment: Do you know how to get a value (of whatever type) out of a dictionary?  Do you know how to get a value out of an array (wherever that array came from)?

Comment: `int[] result = Statistics["DEX"];` or whatever key you like

Comment: `Statistics["STR"][0]`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. So, in the case of, say the key "STR", I would need to do the following

```
int x = Statistics["STR"][1];
```

Comment: This is not meant to discourage or put you down in any way so please don't take offense, but if you figured out the answer five minutes after asking the question, you should try harder to find the solution before asking on Stack Overflow. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) Please also take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!